# Error: "job pending on /dev/sda1" when plugging in USB device

Tags: unix, raspberry-pi

On my raspberry pi running raspbian (unix based i think) I get this error "job pending on /dev/sda1" every time that i plug in my USB flash drive. from my research it has something to do with mounting and un-mounting the device but I'm new to command line and most other posts are over my head. What do i do to fix this error?

if it matters i'm running a script on the pi that writes to that flash drive

Comment: that's not a directory. `/dev/sda` is your primary harddrive/storage system, of which `sda1` is the first partition - e.g. it's usually your boot drive.

Comment: @marc sorry, noted and edited. but i still don't know exactly what that means

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=40487&p=333051

Comment: @filipe I read that whole thread before posting this question, I tried multiple of the commands but as far as i could tell they just gave me more messages that i didn't know what they mean

for example:
    FAT-fs (sda1): Volume was not properly unmounted, Some data may be corupted. Please run fsck
i run fsck and it says WARNING!!!! filesystem is mounted if you continue you ***WILL*** cause ***SEVERE*** filesystem damage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desktop (LXDE for Raspberry Pi) has spotted that you have inserted a USB disc and has tried to mount it.  You can enable or disable this behavior by editing the file `~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE-pi/pcmanfm.conf` and changing the line

```
mount_removable=1
```

to set '0' instead.

You would get that error if there were more than one thing trying to mount your USB disc at the same time.  The second to run will notice that the first has already started a job to mount the disc.

Are you running two copies of your desktop GUI?  (You may not realize that you are, but if you have a VNC or XRDP service you probably will be.)

If that is the cause of your problem (and probably in any event) the message is harmless.  Something will have mounted your USB disc (perhaps you can even see it in `/media`?)  The only infelicity will be that your desktop won't show you the results (e.g. by displaying the drive in a file manager.)

Comment: Yes i am running a XRDP, that makes a lot of sense! Thanks!